# Reorder WooCommerce Hooks

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook, sidebar

I am trying to reorder the hooks in WooCommerce. 
I try to display first the sidebar and then the content. Currently it loads first the products and then the sidebar:

[image: screenshot]

Here are hooks and I have also attached the output the source code:

```
  <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */

        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>
```

Comment: For this, you need to edit woocommerce templates, read this to know how: [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)